# How to use png response in axios get request in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

i send get request to a url and response is a object that contain a **Png** file and i just want to know how can i use this png in my react app ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: Don't use `axios` in the first place. Just assign the URL to an image element:

```
<img src={your_url} alt={suitable_alt_text} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little unclear. You need to state in what way you want to use this data and where you have made the request in your react component.Could you post the full file here and I can give a better answer of how you can do this?

From what I can see you could use this response and use the url returned from the object in the `<img />` element by adding the key `src={data.url}` in the  element, but I need see if you are setting state or however you use it to give you a fuller answer.